# Troubles with installing redmine on linux server Ubuntu 22.04.4

Tags: server, apache2, passenger, redmine

i have get problem with REDMINE.. Could you please help me? I try describe everything i did

I made this install

`sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-passenger`

After configure file **/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby
  PassengerDefaultUser www-data
</IfModule>
```

Also i create **symbolic link for REDMINE**

`sudo ln -s /usr/share/redmine/public /var/www/html/redmine`

**Passenger is enabled**

```
sudo a2enmod passenger
```

This is my configuration of **sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/redmine
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/redmine>
    RailsBaseURI /redmine
    PassengerAppRoot /usr/share/redmine/
    </Directory>
```

When i start my web-browser i got this **error** : [ERROR from web-browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQF6x.jpg)

I also add information from **/var/log/apache2/error.log**

[error log 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABHCs.jpg)

[error log 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cUEJ.jpg)

[error log 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBXkO.jpg)

[errror log 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V7wo.jpg)

I have got also sql installed and configured.

Comment: Were you following redmine install tutorials from redmine.org or you are just trying on your own? Try runing rails s from within redmine's install directory, and fix erros that you see when you do that.

Comment: @AleksandarPavić install by tutorials... What do you mean by runing rails from redmines install directory?

Comment: official tutorial https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineinstall there is how to run it from redmine install directory as well...

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs you paste, you have an issue when connecting to the servers of phusion passenger that provide a security check. That is probably caused by a firewall that's filtering outgoing connections.

You can get more info about this feature on their site [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/security_update_check.html).

In case you want to disable the security check there's the parameter to change the default [info](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerdisablesecurityupdatecheck)

> PassengerDisableSecurityUpdateCheck on